# What do the quotes mean in this SQL Server snippet? (SELECT '' column1, '' column 2)

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax

I'd like to know the purpose of the two single quotes in front of each column. This is in a stored procedure. Thank you for your help!

```
INSERT INTO #temptable1
SELECT DISTINCT '' column1
    ,column2
    ,'' column3
    ,'' column4     
FROM table1
WHERE column1 NOT LIKE 'string1%'
    AND column2 <> 'string2'
    AND column3 <> 'string3'
```

Comment: `'' column1` means an empty string with alias "column1"

Comment: Use NULL intstead of ' ' blank string. Null wont occupy any memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `''` is an empty string.  So this is using an empty string instead of `NULL` for "missing" values.

I would write this code as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT '' as column1, column2, '' as column3, '' as column4
```

This might make it clearer.  I always use `as` for column aliases -- so it is easier to spot missing commas (there should always be an `as` for a column alias).

More commonly, this would probably just use default values (which are usually `NULL` but could be `''`):

```
INSERT INTO #temptable1 (column2)
    SELECT DISTINCT column2
    FROM table1
    WHERE column1 NOT LIKE 'string1%'
        AND column2 <> 'string2'
        AND column3 <> 'string3';
```